# Search inside columns which has space and multiple combination of phone numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table which contains customer phone numbers, this numbers are filled with different formats, for eg some times, +91 803 22 22 22 and some time +91802323232 and sometime 803242525.
The question is when I do a search using mysql for eg `select * from customer where phone LIKE %803222222%` this is not showing any result, because the value stored inside the field has whitespace.

What will be the possible solution for this ?

Regards,

Comment: It's strongly recommended to store phones in single format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spaces from the `phone` field before doing the `LIKE` check:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE REPLACE(phone, ' ', '') LIKE '%803222222%'; -- matches +91 803 22 22 22
```